# Adding thief and mlp.thief forecasting functions in forecast.gts (i.e. fmethod = c("ets", "arima", "rw", "thief", "mlp.thief", "elm.thief"))?

Tags: r, hierarchical-data, forecasting, forecast

I have a hierarchical data. The data has the following levels (top to down):

1. Production facility
2. Industry
3. Costumer
4. Product group
5. SKU

I am forecasting using `r` library `hts`. To increase accuracy I would like to use `thief` library (also `nnfor::mlp.thief` and `nnfor::elm.thief` functions). I added these functions to `forecast.hts()` in the following way,

```
loopfn <- function(x, ...) {
    out <- list()
    if (is.null(FUN)) {
      if (fmethod == "ets") {
        models <- forecast::ets(x, lambda = lambda, ...)
        out$pfcasts <- forecast::forecast(models, h = h, PI = FALSE)$mean
      } else if (fmethod == "arima") {


        models <- forecast::auto.arima(x, lambda = lambda, xreg = xreg,
                             parallel = FALSE, ...)
        out$pfcasts <- forecast::forecast(models, h = h, xreg = newxreg)$mean


      } else if (fmethod == "rw") {
        models <- forecast::rwf(x, h = h, lambda = lambda, ...)
        out$pfcasts <- models$mean
      } else if (fmethod == "thief"){

        models <- thief::thief(x, h = h , usemodel = usemodel, ...)
        out$pfcasts <- models$mean
      }else if (fmethod == "mlp.thief"){

        models <- nnfor::mlp.thief(x, h = h , ...)
        out$pfcasts <- models$mean
      } else if (fmethod == "elm.thief"){

        models <- nnfor::elm.thief(x, h = h , ...)
        out$pfcasts <- models$mean
      }


    } else { # user defined function to produce point forecasts
      models <- FUN(x, ...)
      if (is.null(newxreg)) {
        out$pfcasts <- forecast(models, h = h)$mean
      } else {
        out$pfcasts <- forecast(models, h = h, xreg = newxreg)$mean
      }
    }
    if (keep.fitted) {
      out$fitted <- stats::fitted(models)
    }
    if (keep.resid) {
      out$resid <- stats::residuals(models)
    }
    return(out)
  }
```

Would there be any theoretical problem to do so? In fact, it increases forecast accuracy.

considering the following literature I do not see any problem though [Hyndman et.al. 2017](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/temporalhierarchies.pdf) and [Hyndman et.al. 2011](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/Hierarchical6.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could use any function with the argument `FUN =`
The function has to be forecast object.

Answer (score 0):

I used a kind of similar method to forecast Brazilian fiscal revenues before the Covid-19 (but I was using the `nnetar` function which is theorically an MLP)

Hierarchical forecasting is completly independant of the model you are using.

You can even use judgemental forecasting (but in this case, you have to use `nseries` reconciliation)

So no problem about using `elm.thief'.